# Запустить код - скрипт python на удённом сервере

Tags: python, python-3.x

Не могу сообразить как это сделать, на сколько я понимаю через Paramiko не получится, через него например я могу выполнить какую то команду ОС, но не весь код.
Есть вот такой небольшой скрипт, который проверят модифицированные файлы в каталоге. Его я выполняю со своего компа локально, всё ок.
Сейчас хочу со своего локального компа этот код - скрипт что бы обрабатывался на сервере.
Есть какие то мысли?

```
now = dt.datetime.now()
now1 = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk("C:/Users/admin/Desktop/FULL"):
        for fname in files:
            path = os.path.join(root, fname)
            st = os.stat(path)
            mtime = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
            mtime1 = time.strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(st.st_mtime))
            if mtime == now1:
                print('%s modified %s'%(path[36:48], mtime1))
    exit()
```

Comment: Вот тут можно посмотреть, если у вас bash https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20499074/run-local-python-script-on-remote-server